# Property change listener for Archaius

Tags: java, apache-commons-config, netflix-archaius

I'm using [Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius) to keep system properties aligned between all the servers hosting my app. I can see all the property getters can take a callback to be called whenever that property changes (for instance see the [third argument in `getStringProperty()`](http://netflix.github.io/archaius/archaius-core-javadoc/com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory.html#getStringProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Runnable))) but I want to listen for *any* property change. Is there some interface I can implement and register as a listener somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not find an answer in any of the Archaius How-to documentation, but Apache Commons Configuration does provide a solution in their [Configuration Events](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_events.html) documentation (which Archaius is fully compatible with).

I created a listener by implementing `org.apache.commons.configuration.event.ConfigurationListener`, which defines a single method called `configurationChanged()` and takes a single `ConfigurationEvent` parameter. This method is called once before and once after the property actually changes, with a `beforeUpdate` boolean on the `event` parameter indicating the timing for each call.

Once I created the listener, I registered it with my Archaius configuration manager:

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().addConfigurationListener(new MyCustomConfigurationListener());
```

Now I can see `MyCustomConfigurationListener.configurationChanged()` is called twice (once before and once after) on every property change.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks Cameron!

Comment: Is this solution scalable, meaning if we have several instances will it fire event for all instances or this is just works for the instance for which update called?